# How to add an image beside to an input checkbox

Tags: html, symfony

I have a the following checkbox field (1)
and I would like to add an image to the checkbox.

I added it in twig file in the following way (2) but it is bad placed.
I would like to place it in the following way (3)

```
// (1)
->add('remove_avatar', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'user.label.current_avatar',
    'required' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
))

// (2)
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<span class="user">
    <img src="{{ get_avatar(user) }}" class="user-avatar">
</span>

// (3)
<div class="controls">
    <img src="some_like">
    <input type="checkbox" id="profile_remove_avatar" name="profile[remove_avatar]" value="1">
    <label class="control-label" for="profile_remove_avatar">Remove the current avatar</label>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering the total form with only `form_widget(form)` you can do more if you render each field for itself. Like this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <img src="some_like">
    {{ form_widget(form.remove_avatar) }}
    {{ form_label(form.remove_avatar) }}
</div>
```

If you got more fields in your form render them the same way **OR** place them all at the end with `form_rest(form)`.

This is how you customize a symfony2 form from inside a twig template. So i think this is the best and easiest way.